# Send entire html code with client:send() in Nodemcu Esp8266 lua programming

Tags: sockets, http, lua, webserver, esp8266

I created a lua file that implements a 2relay module to control a rolling shutter through a website.
I followed the *led_webserver* example and I extended my code from there.
I tried so many ways to **send a full html page** with the function `client:send()`,
but it doesn't seem to work.

---

It's a page I developed myself and it works on the pc but I couldn't find an easy way to send it.
I declare a local variable (for example *test*) that contains all the html code and then i put it as parameter in `client:send(test).
Does someone know another way to do so?

Answer (score 2):

The TCP stack on the eps8266 doesn't support streaming across IP packets. Each send can be up to one full IP packet but longer than that and you have send them packet by packet using the `soc:on("sent",callback)`.  See the [nodeMCU Unofficial FAQ](http://www.esp8266.com/wiki/doku.php?id=nodemcu-unofficial-faq) for more discussion of this.

Answer (score 1):

Other posters have given a lot of good information, but I don't think there was a good specific solution to this problem given yet, even in the unofficial FAQ.

To send large static files, you can load them from flash and send them in chunks, using callbacks. As other people have mentioned, there is a limit to how much can be sent with a single call. And multiple send calls in a single callback may not be processed as you expect them to, and may take too much memory. Here is a short example loading and sending a file in chunks:

```
local idx = 0 --keep track of where we are in the file
local fname = "index.html"

function nextChunk(c) --open file, read a chunk, and send it!
      file.open(fname)
      file.seek("set", idx)
      local str = file.read(500)
      if not str then return end --no more to send. 
      c:send(str)
      idx = idx + 500
      file.close() --close the file to let other callbacks use the filesystem
end
client:on("sent", nextChunk) --every time we send a chunk, start the next one!
nextChunk(client) --send the first chunk.
```

or, using coroutines and a timer, we can make it more flexible:

```
local ready = true --represents whether we are ready to send again
client:on("sent", function() ready=true end) --we are ready after sending the previous chunk is finished.

local function sendFile(fname)
    local idx=0 --keep track of where we are in the file
    while true do
        file.open(fname)
        file.seek("set", idx)
        local str = file.read(500)
        if not str then return end --no more to send. 
        c:send(str)
        ready=false --we have sent something. we are no longer ready.
        idx = idx + 500
        file.close() --close the file to let other callbacks use the filesystem
        coroutine.yield() --give up control to the caller
    end
end

local sendThread = coroutine.create(sendFile)
tmr.alarm(0, 100, 1, function() --make a repeating alarm that will send the file chunk-by-chunk
    if ready then coroutine.resume(sendThread, "index.html") end
    if coroutine.status(sendThread) == "dead" then tmr.stop(0) end --stop when we are done
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
    buf = "<h1> ESP8266 Web Server</h1>";
    buf = buf.."<h2>Subtitle</h2>";
    client:send(buf);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sending more than a couple hundred bytes in one call fails more often than not.  Also realize that multiple successive calls to send within the same lua chunk are queued and performed asynchronously after the chunk returns -- this consumes impractical amounts of memory.

So building a page of any complexity at all with runtime values concatenated in  is problematic. A more rational approach is for the ESP8266 to just return data as JSON, and serve the fancy pages from a PC, with embedded script to query the ESP and fold the data into the page.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution for this.
I had to send a large file containing text and I used the following code for it:

```
    file.open("example.txt","r") 
    for counter=1, numboflinesinfile-1 do
    client:send(file.readline() .. "<br>");  
    end           
    file.close()
```

counter is just a counting variable
numberoflinesinfile is the number of lines you want to send.

Not a clean solution and maybe violating all program rules but working as a charm.

Comment: Please refrain from promoting your blog in the answers section on Stack Overflow. You can instead add a link to it from your profile page. Thanks!

Comment: Not a good idea. Due to the asynchronous nature of NodeMCU there's no guarantee the nth `client:send()` is done before n+1th `client:send()` is invoked. See Terry's answer for it should be done.